# How do I convert an array of objects to an array of elements, and then place them inside main div root element by using map and foreach methods?

Tags: javascript

The `makePostEl` function should create an element from a post and return it.
The element is created based on the post type.
The `makeWall` function should convert the array of posts into an array of elements, and then place all these elements inside `rootEl`.  Using map and `forEach` is required.

```js
const posts = [
  { id: 3, type: 'text', content: 'Final Week!', },
  { id: 2, type: 'image', content: './img/logo_js.svg', },
  { id: 1, type: 'video', content: './video/video.ogv', },
];

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

function makePostEl(post) {
  if (post.type === 'text') {
    const div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.setAttribute('data-type', 'text');
    div1.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
    const div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.textContent = post.content;
    div1.appendChild(div2);
  } else if (post.type === 'video') {
    const div3 = document.createElement('div');
    div3.setAttribute('data-type', 'video');
    div3.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
    const video1 = document.createElement('video');
    video1.src = post.content;
    video1.controls = true;
    div3.appendChild(video1);
  } else if (post.type === 'image') {
    const div4 = document.createElement('div');
    div4.setAttribute('data-type', 'image');
    div4.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
    const image1 = document.createElement('img');
    image1.src = post.content;
    div4.appendChild(image1);
  }
}

makePostEl(posts);

function makeWall(el, items) {
  items.map(makePostEl).forEach(/*code*/);
}

makeWall(rootEl, posts);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put indented code please?

Comment: You've explained what should happen, but not what ***specific*** problem you are having. I'd start but looking in your console for the line that your current code throws its error on and debug that.

Comment: You are also not using `.map()` correctly.

Comment: Also DRY - Don't repeat yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this

You need to return the divs you create

```js
const posts = [
  { id: 3, type: 'text', content: 'Final Week!', },
  { id: 2, type: 'image', content: './img/logo_js.svg', },
  { id: 1, type: 'video', content: './video/video.ogv', },
];

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

function makePostEl(post) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('data-type', post.type);
  div.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
  const div1 = document.createElement('div');
  if (post.type === "text") {
    div1.textContent = post.content;
  } else if (post.type === 'video') {
    const video1 = document.createElement('video');
    video1.src = post.content;
    video1.controls = true;
    div1.appendChild(video1);
  } else if (post.type === 'image') {
    const image1 = document.createElement('img');
    image1.src = post.content;
    div1.appendChild(image1);
  }

  div.appendChild(div1);
  return div
}

posts.forEach(post => rootEl.appendChild(makePostEl(post)))
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use Array.map function, that applies your function to every element of an array

following code may be an answer:

```
const posts = [
  { id: 3, type: 'text', content: 'Final Week!', },
  { id: 2, type: 'image', content: './img/logo_js.svg', },
  { id: 1, type: 'video', content: './video/video.ogv', },
];

function makePostEl(data){
  let element;
  
  switch(data.type){
    case 'text': 
      element = document.createElement('p')
      element.textContent = data.content;
    break;
    case: 'image':
      element = document.createElement('img');
      element.src = data.content;
    break;
    case: 'video':
      element = document.createElement('video');
      element.src = data.content;
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }
  return element;
}

function convertObjectsToElements(dataArray){
  return dataArray.map(data=>makePostEl(data))
}

convertObjectsToElements(posts)
```

then you can use appendChild to add it to your document, but it is up to you.

```
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');
convertObjectsToElements(posts).forEach(elem=>root.appendChild(elem))
```

to nest them use another method:

```js
function nestElements(dataArray){
  
  for(int i = 1, len = dataArray.length; i< len; i++){
    dataArray[i-1].appendChild(dataArray[i]);
  }
  return dataArray;

}

//there we add these elements to root

function makeWall(posts, root){
  addNestedElementsToRoot(convertObjectsToElements(posts)).forEach(elem=>root.appendChild(elem))

}

makeWall(posts,root)
```

Comment: The problem is I need to use both functions to achieve the results of having to nest all those elements inside rootEl. I have tried to use appendChild inside makePostEl and it works perfectly but this exercise strictly asks to use .map() and forEach () methods inside makeWall function to achieve that same result.

Comment: @Siyavush what about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misinterpreting your requirements. Saying that `.map()` and `.forEach()` should be used, doesn't necessarily mean "together on the same line". In actuality, your project requires `.map()` for `makePostEl()` and `.forEach()` for `.makeWall()`.

And, `.map()` is meant to iterate over an array and then return a new array with items returned from the loop.

See comments inline below.

```js
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

const posts = [
  { id: 3, type: 'text', content: 'Final Week!', },
  { id: 2, type: 'image', content: './img/logo_js.svg', },
  { id: 1, type: 'video', content: './video/video.ogv', },
];

let elements = []; // <-- .map() will return items here

// You're passing in an array here, so you need to
// iterate over the items within it.
function makePostEl(posts) {
  // The empty array will recieve the .map() return values
  elements = posts.map(function(post){
    if (post.type === 'text') {
      const div1 = document.createElement('div');
      div1.setAttribute('data-type', 'text');
      div1.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
      div1.textContent = post.content;
      // When inside of a .map() loop, you return
      // items that you want added to the .map() array
      return div1;
    } else if (post.type === 'video') {
      const div3 = document.createElement('div');
      div3.setAttribute('data-type', 'video');
      div3.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
      const video1 = document.createElement('video');
      video1.src = post.content;
      video1.controls = true;
      return video1;
    } else if (post.type === 'image') {
      const div4 = document.createElement('div');
      div4.setAttribute('data-type', 'image');
       div4.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
      const image1 = document.createElement('img');
      image1.src = post.content;
      return image1;
    }
  });
}

function makeWall(el, items) {
 // Here, you don't need to return anything, so
 // just a loop with .forEach() will do. But you'll 
 // loop over the .map() array of elements now,
 // not the intial array of objects.
 items.forEach(function(element){
   el.appendChild(element) // Add the element to the document
 });
}

makePostEl(posts);    
makeWall(rootEl, elements);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your feedback and providing your own solutions. Looking at your code, I came up with a solution that worked perfectly.

```
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

function makePostEl(post) {

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('data-type', post.type);
  div.setAttribute('data-id', post.id);
  const div1 = document.createElement('div');
  if (post.type === 'text') {
    div1.textContent = post.content;
    div.appendChild(div1);
  } else if (post.type === 'video') {
    const video1 = document.createElement('video');
    video1.src = post.content;
    video1.controls = true;
    div.appendChild(video1);
  } else if (post.type === 'image') {
    const image1 = document.createElement('img');
    image1.src = post.content;
    div.appendChild(image1);
  }
  return div;
}
function makeWall(el, items) {
  items.map(makePostEl).forEach((post) => el.appendChild(post));
}

makeWall(rootEl, posts);
```